# which util package would be useful to store Parent child relationship data in java

Tags: java

I have a Tree structure like data from the database, there will be Single parent and to its multiple levels of childrens,

I am able to create the db table and store according to that structure, 
Now I need to display the data on to the jsp page.

My questions, which data strucuture would be more effective to traverse the data from DB to JSP page.

I am using DB2 database for that, I am not using Hibernate for this application, its just core java, jsp pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use HashMap for this perpose in following way:

```
Map<String,<ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String,<ArrayList<String>>();
```

The `key` part would store the parent name . And the `value` part contains the list of children belonging to that parent.